# php regex to find what precedes a space

Tags: php, regex

How to find a regex that can find me only the url's from those vars,

basically there is a space always after the url.

```
$var1 = 'http://www.asdasgdst.com/thebook.html Result: chosen nickname "doodoo"; success (from first page)';

$var2 = 'http://adfhdfdfcvxn.com/blog/2008/12/28/beginnings/comment-page-1/#comment-8203 Result: chosen nickname "zvika"; success (from first page);';

$var3 = 'http://sdfsd.sdfjstestgg.com/453980.html?mode=reply Result: chosen nickname "sharon"; success; not working;';

$var4 = 'http://www.yuuyok.net/index.php?sub=community&site=posts&thread_id= Result: chosen nickname "kelly"; success (from first page);';
```

Comment: What if there's a space **in** the URL?

Answer (score 3):

If all the string look like that then simply:

```
/^([^ ]*)/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `explode` for this, which will be much more efficient.

```
$url = array_pop(explode(" ", $var1, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
'/(^http.*?)\s/'
```

This should match all the strings that are starting with http until a whitespace is found

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick:

```
preg_match('~^(http://.*?) Result:~', $var1, $match);
$url = $match[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

i'd go for:

```
preg_match('/(http:[^ ]+)/s', $var, $arr);
$url = $arr[0];
```

just in case the var isn't starting with http

besides, in order to test it you can try this regex (or any other):

```
(http:[^ ]+)
```

at: http://www.regextester.com/